# Can't upload to S3 from production on Lightsail

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-lightsail

My backend is currently hosted on AWS Lightsail, I noticed I'm unable to upload images on my production server only but on my local enviroment this works fine, I found the following error while browsing through my logs:

```
[15/Sep/2021:23:27:53] AccessDenied: Access Denied
[15/Sep/2021:23:27:53] at Request.extractError (/usr/src/app/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/services/s3.js:714:35)
[15/Sep/2021:23:27:53] at Request.callListeners (/usr/src/app/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)
[15/Sep/2021:23:27:53] at Request.emit (/usr/src/app/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
[15/Sep/2021:23:27:53] at Request.emit (/usr/src/app/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:688:14)
[15/Sep/2021:23:27:53] at Request.transition (/usr/src/app/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
[15/Sep/2021:23:27:53] at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/usr/src/app/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
[15/Sep/2021:23:27:53] at /usr/src/app/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
[15/Sep/2021:23:27:53] at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
[15/Sep/2021:23:27:53] at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:690:12)
[15/Sep/2021:23:27:53] at Request.callListeners (/usr/src/app/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18) {
[15/Sep/2021:23:27:53] code: 'AccessDenied',
[15/Sep/2021:23:27:53] region: null,
[15/Sep/2021:23:27:53] time: 2021-09-15T23:27:53.960Z,
[15/Sep/2021:23:27:53] requestId: 'A39S3K86W7SR08M2',
[15/Sep/2021:23:27:53] extendedRequestId: '0MM41112KWFTx72LFSZx1UmNkCdDXh5LQlSz8lIN9L3Opgt1IsEdhdYqRBoyXWXOxStdUTWO6MM=',
[15/Sep/2021:23:27:53] cfId: undefined,
[15/Sep/2021:23:27:53] statusCode: 403,
[15/Sep/2021:23:27:53] retryable: false,
[15/Sep/2021:23:27:53] retryDelay: 80.77429353875539
[15/Sep/2021:23:27:53] }
```

So it seems like this is an error on S3? Am I supposed to update access to my S3 bucket even though it is publicly accessible?

Comment: You need credentials to write to the bucket even if its publicly viewable

Comment: Just because a bucket is “publicly accessible” doesn’t mean that anyone can just write any arbitrary file they want to it - is this your intention? Why would you want to do this?

Comment: I configured a IAM User for uploading and removing pictures from AWS, I just want profile images and other assets to be stored on S3.

Comment: It sounds like you are using the IAM User on your own computer, and it works fine. Question: How have you provided credentials to your program that is running on the Lightsail instance? Is it using exactly the _same_ credentials?

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous reasons why you would see a `403 Access Denied` for `S3` buckets:

- Bucket, IAM user policy if exists. Look out for any deny statements and ensure that your request from `Lightsail` meets the condition specified in both bucket, IAM policy
- IAM Permission boundary allowing access to S3, if exists
- Service Control policy at the AWS Organization level allowing access to S3, if exists
- S3 access credentials, user or role (long term / temporary)

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue creating a `LightSailUserProd` with the s3-policy attached, and generating the credentials using CloudFormation (AccessKey & Secret). I'm already using CodeDeploy Agent, so I had a `user` per On-Premise instance, this is **Not** an **EC2 Instance**.

Then I put those values on the "Initial bash script".
You will need to use `sudo aws <command>` inside lightsail, because credentials are placed on `/root/` (in my case).
Alternatively, you can place it on `/home/*`, so `bitnami` user will have that profile by default, and there is no need to use sudo.

bash:

```sh
 # env.vars
 echo "STAGE=${STAGE}" >> /etc/environment
 # aws credentials
 cat <<EOT >> /etc/codedeploy-agent/conf/codedeploy.onpremises.yml 
 aws_access_key_id: <acceskey_id>
 aws_secret_access_key: <acceskey_secret>
 iam_user_arn: <user_arn>
 region: <REGION>
 EOT
 sudo mkdir /root/.aws
 sudo cat <<EOT >> /root/.aws/credentials 
 [default]
 aws_access_key_id=${acceskey_id}
 aws_secret_access_key=${acceskey_secret}
 region=${REGION}
```

CloudFormation template

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: >
Buckets used for deployment 

Resources:
  AssetsBucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      BucketName: !Sub yourservice-assets-${AWS::Region}
      PublicAccessBlockConfiguration:
          BlockPublicAcls: true
          BlockPublicPolicy: true
          IgnorePublicAcls: true
          RestrictPublicBuckets: true

 AssetsManagedBucketPolicy:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy'
    Properties:
      Description: s3 bucket for assets
      ManagedPolicyName: yourservice-s3-assets-bucket-managed-policy
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Action: s3:*
          Resource:
            - !GetAtt AssetsBucket.Arn
            - !Sub ${AssetsBucket.Arn}/*

  LightsailUser:
    Type: AWS::IAM::User
    Properties:
      Path: "/"
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - !Ref CodeDeployManagedBucketPolicy
        - !Ref AssetsManagedBucketPolicy

# This UserAccesskey will be generated only once, so you MUST export the values
  LightsailUserAccesskey:
    Type: AWS::IAM::AccessKey
    Properties:
      UserName:
        !Ref LightsailUser

Outputs:
  LightsailUserArn:
    Description: Arn of the LightSail user
    Value: !GetAtt LightsailUser.Arn
    Export:
      Name: yourservice-lightsail-user-arn
  LightsailUserAccesskeySecret:
    Description: Accesskey.secret of the LigthSail user
    Value: !GetAtt LightsailUserAccesskey.SecretAccessKey
    Export:
      Name: yourservice-lightsail-user-accesskey-secret
  LightsailUserAccesskeyId:
    Description: Accesskey.id of the LigthSail user
    Value: !Ref LightsailUserAccesskey
    Export:
      Name: yourservice-lightsail-user-accesskey-id
```

deploy cloudFormation template

```sh
aws cloudformation deploy \
      --profile default \
      --region us-east-1  \
      --template-file lightsail-artifacts.yml \
      --stack-name yourservice-artifacts-us-east-1 \
      --capabilities CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM
```

Comment: Using the instance roles is a much cleaner solution and preferred today, then there is no need store any fixed credentials

Comment: I use CodeDeploy, so in my case I had already a `user` for each On-Premise instance.

Answer (score 0):

> update access to my S3 bucket even though it is publicly accessible?

*publicly accessible* means that an unauthenticated user can read objects. It is usually a bad idea to have the bucket public and you should be able to justify it. Common option is to give users access to the s3 resources using a presigned url generated by the application.

> unable to upload images on my production server only but on my local enviroment this works fine,

Check your lightsail instance role and you need to add s3:PutObject permission there (maybe a few more write permissions depending how do you upload, tag,..)

See the documentation: https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/security_iam

`To assign an role to an EC2 instance and make it available to all of its applications, you create an instance profile that is attached to the instance.`

There may be more places limiting access to the s3 services or objects (see the answer from Piyush), but let's start with giving access through the instance role.